# Finding an unknown point on an infinite number line

Tags: algorithms

Given a number line from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, there exists a point $P$ on the line. We need to find the minimum number of steps to get to $P$ subject to the following constraints:

1. The value of $P$ is not known.
2. At a time you can only move one step either backward or forward. For example: if you are currently at 1, you can either go to 0 or 2 but not to -1 or 3 directly.

According to me, if $P$ were known then we could see what indices are reachable from $P$, and then choose the one that is closest to it.
But because this is an infinite number line, and since we don't know what the value of $P$ is, I am not able to come up with any suggestions and would appreciate if I could get some tips.

Comment: If there was a starting point different from `−∞` and `∞` and way to recognise $P$ when *I'm there*, I'd change my mind every now and then, trying to keep the number of steps I need on the order of the distance to $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is known as the cow path problem. You can find many online resources explaining how to solve it, for example [this page](https://algnotes.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/cow-path-problem/) on *Algorithms Notes*.